Missing Permissions (business_management, leads_retrieval) in Access Token Despite User Approval
I am experiencing an issue with the Facebook API where certain permissions requested by my application are not being included in the user's access token, even though the user has granted all requested permissions.
Requested Permissions:
ads_management
business_management
leads_retrieval
pages_manage_ads
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_engagement
pages_show_list
Observed Behavior: After the user grants all the requested permissions, the access token retrieved only includes the following permissions:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "pages_show_list",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "ads_management",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_read_engagement",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_manage_metadata",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "pages_manage_ads",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}

Missing Permissions:
business_management
leads_retrieval
Impact: The absence of the leads_retrieval permission causes the following error when accessing the endpoint https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxx/subscribed_apps:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) To subscribe to the leadgen field, one of these permissions is needed: leads_retrieval",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "ANFgjRDObuYno84WEkPHOED"
  }
}

